# Identity User FK

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I've an application in Asp.NET Core 3.1 MVC with EF Core and Identity.

I've two tables `Calls` and `AspNetUsers`. `AspNetUsers` has many `Calls` and one `Call` has one `AspNetUsers`.

The `Calls` table structure is okay, I think. But now I need to get `Calls` from `AspNetUsers`.

In `CallsController` I'm trying: `IList<Call> calls = this.User.Calls;` but no success.

I tried:

```
IList<Call> calls = this._context.Calls.Where(x => x.UserId == this._userManager.GetUserId(this.User)).ToList();
```

I've success. But do it is correct?

So, in application i've identity classes and an `ApplicationUser` like this:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual IList<Call> Calls { get; set; }
}
```

And in `Startup` class in `ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => 
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

So, What's the better way to get Calls from AspNetUsers? *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `ApplicationUser` like :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Call> Calls { get; set; }
}
```

Call.cs:

```
public class Call
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

In ApplicationDbContext , add :

```
public virtual DbSet<Call> Calls { get; set; } //add this line 
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}
```

Then you can query the current user's call by :

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var userID = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var calls = _applicationDbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Calls).First(u => u.Id == userID).Calls.ToList();

    //or
    var callsa = _applicationDbContext.Calls.Where(p => p.UserID == userID).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I thought that i wold can to do: `applicationUser.Calls`. Has a way?

Comment: `_applicationDbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Calls).First(u => u.Id == userID)` ,then you can .Calls

Comment: @AugustoHenrique Please mark reply as answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationUser should be

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       public virtual ICollection<Call> Calls { get; set; }
    }
```

Call entity should be

```
 public class Call
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //...

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ApplicationUserId))]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
 }
```

and, of course, you should override the OnModeCreating method in your DbContext like this

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options){}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Call>()
                        .HasOne(x => x.ApplicationUser)
                        .WithMany(x => x.Calls);
        }

        //...DbSets..

     }
```

and finally, load all your calls in Calls collection of ApplicationUser

```
  var user = await _context.ApplicationUsers.FindAsync(_userManager.GetUserId(this.User));

  await context.Entry(user)
      .Collection(x => x.Calls)
      .LoadAsync();
```

Now, you have all your calls loaded in Calls collection of the current user.